# Mongodb aggregation with $or nested clauses

Tags: python, mongodb

I have mongodb documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d35ba501545d248c383871f"),
    "key1" : 1,
    "currentTime" : ISODate("2019-07-18T19:41:54.000Z"),
    "iState" : "START - 1",
    "errGyro" : -4.0,
    "states" : [ 
        {
            "ts" : 3,
            "accY" : -165.877227783203,
            "gyroZ" : 8.2994499206543,
        },
    {
            "ts" : 4,
            "accY" : -15.843573,
            "gyroZ" : 12.434643,
        },
    {
            "ts" : 3,
            "accY" : 121.32667,
            "gyroZ" : 98.45566,
        } 

    ]
}
```

I want to return all the states objects and the parent document where "ts" is 3 or 5.

I tried this query at first:

```
db.getCollection('logs').find(
{"states" : 
    { "$elemMatch" : { "$or":[
        { "ts": 
            { "$eq" : 3}
        },
        { "ts": 
            { "$eq" : 5}
        }
    ]
       }
   }  
    },{"states.$":1 })
```

But this returns only the first "state" document where the "eq" occurred.
How can I return all the matching documents?
Thank you.

Comment: try removing `$` from project parameter {"states":1 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $elemMatch returns only the first matching element of array, you have to use aggregation to achieve your goal. Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "states.ts": {
            $eq: 3
          }
        },
        {
          "states.ts": {
            $eq: 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      states: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$states"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "states.ts": {
            $eq: 3
          }
        },
        {
          "states.ts": {
            $eq: 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      states: {
        $push: "$states"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

First $match and $project stages are here for query optimization and memory save, if many documents are returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation pipelines

```
db.getCollection('logs').aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$states"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                { "states.ts": 3 },
                { "states.ts": 5 },
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            "key1": { $first: "key1" },
            "currentTime": { $first: "currentTime" },
            "iState": { $first: "$iState" },
            "errGyro": { $first: "$errGyro" },
            states: { $push: "$states" }
        }
    }
])
```